# Window functions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This one will be quick. I can't get exactly what I want out of the `row_number()` function.  What I get:
[image]

I need the `row_number()` to increment only on different `patid`s that have different `dailyDosage`.  So rows 4-9 on the screen cap should all be 1.  Row 13 should be 1 (because it's a new patid) and row 14 should be 2 (because of the change in daily dosage.  What I get:

```
select distinct 
     ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by rx.patid,quantity/daysSup*cast(REPLACE(LEFT(strength,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',strength)),'m','') as int) 
     order by rx.patid,quantity/daysSup*cast(REPLACE(LEFT(strength,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',strength)),'m','') as int))
     ,rx.patid
    ,rx.drugName
    ,rx.strength
    ,rx.quantity
    ,rx.daysSup
    ,rx.fillDate
    ,quantity/daysSup*cast(REPLACE(LEFT(strength,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',strength)),'m','') as int) as dailyDosage
    from rx 
    inner join (select distinct m.patid, m.sex, m.injurylevel from members as m) as m on m.PATID=rx.patid
    where ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(LEFT(strength,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',strength)),'m',''))=1 
    and REPLACE(LEFT(strength,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',strength)),'m','') not like '%.%' 
    and drugname in ('baclofen')
    and daysSup !=0 and quantity !=0
    and daysSup > 1
    order by rx.patid
```

SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Yikes, have you considered making `REPLACE(LEFT(strength,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',strength)),'m','')` a computed column?

Comment: No, not familiar with that methodology.  That ugly mess is to extract integer amounts from things like '100MG' or '10mg'.  Works, and since nobody else has to look at it (until now, i suppose) I thought what the heck, let's roll with it.

Comment: You should always consider the concept of not repeating yourself. Scalar UDFs in SQL Server are a counter-example but it's usually best to perform those calculations in a central place and as few times as possible.

Comment: Haven't really gotten that far in my implementation of SQL :).  I always welcome a more scalable, industry standard solution but the first SQL book I went through didn't mention UDFs and I haven't gotten there in my new one.

Comment: I'm not suggesting a UDF. I'm suggesting a computed column. If your book doesn't mention those, there are other books and Google.

Comment: @AaronBertrand had no idea what they were called.  Trawling google now that I know. thanks.

Comment: If it's a one off calculation, you can use the WITH keyword and perform a query that gets your columns with the calculated one, and then followed by the query that contains the window function.  Also useful when you use a calculation in a group by to avoid repeating the calculation.  I use WITH quite liberally to break my queries up into distinct steps and avoid duplicating complex calculations when they are very complex.  AKA Common Table Expressions.  You can chain them together and others can even piece meal run them up to a certain point to see intermediate result sets.

Comment: @AaronBertrand thanks for the great suggestion for the computed column.  made things way easier and faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are trying to rank the daily dosages.  Try using `dense_rank` rather than `row_nubmer`.

Row_number enumerates the rows.  Ranks keep the same values together.  Dense_rank does the enumeration, assigning the first group 1's, the next group 2's, and so on.  Rank leaves gaps in the numbering.

Answer (score 5):

You should change your `ROW_NUMBER` and use `RANK`.